# Can anybody suggest cheap Test Robots like TurtleBots that could be bought and which runs on ROS?

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to buy a real robot so that I could test out some of my source code and see how it works on a real robot. I wanted to buy TurtleBot but it is very expensive around $2000. Can anybody suggest any cheaper ones??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192937/can-anybody-suggest-cheap-test-robots-like-turtlebots-that-could-be-bought-and-which-runs-on-ros?/) by [ish45](https://answers.ros.org/users/20021/ish45/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-09-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-09-18**:
You should maybe specify, what your robot should be able to do, which sensors it should have and so on. You could look into kits, that transform your smartphone into a driving robot. Would propably be the best bang for the buck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're willing to put in a few hours of work in you can very easily build your own turtlebot. Just by a compatible base like the irobot create or the kobuki which has ROS support and then add your cpu/sensors on top. The kobuki especially comes with enough paraphenalia so that you don't need to wire any electronics for a basic turtlebot-like configuration (just plug'n play). This will save you a good chunk of money.

The turtlebot source code can then be a very good reference as to how you can arrange your launchers and robot description to completely ros'ify your robot.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-09-18**:
+1. I doubt you could find anything cheaper than Turtlebot that's completely off-the-shelf, but costs can be reduced based on how much you're willing to rig yourself. It's also a great learning experience for ROS that gives you an understanding of the system and hardware.